# How Using tempdata to pass data entered by user in a data field from view to another view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I am new to MVC.  I one please help me on how to assign value entered by user (for instance table column such as username) in a view to TempData.
I also want to pass the assigned data to a column in another view

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please add essential parts of your code. Read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for asking a better received question.

Answer (score 0):

In your view, add a form field:

```
<input name="myfield" type="text" />
```

In your controller's action, get the field and store it in TempData:

```
public ActionResult ProcessIt(string myfield)
{
  TempData["yourkey"] = myfield;
  return RedirectToAction("SomeOtherAction");
}
```

Now you can use it in the SomeOtherAction view:

```
<div>Entered data: @TempData["yourkey"]</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response, l wish to assign the value to the TempData at the first view and when I post back to the server the stored data of the temdata should be transfer to the other field specified in the redirectToAction method.

Comment: This is another question. I believe I answered your initial question in which case you'd help other users by accepting my answer.

Comment: thanks this was helpful. basically, since move involved only one field the second answer also handled it well.  thank you

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I am creating web test, the controller for the question

public async Task Create([Bind(Include = "QuestionID,Question")]
        TestQuestion testQuestion, string command, FormCollection QuestionData)
        {

```
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.TestQuestions.Add(testQuestion);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();

            return RedirectToAction("Create", "TestOptions");

        }
```

The controller for the options:

public async Task Create([Bind(Include = "OptionID,QuestionID,OptionA")] TestOption testOption)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.TestOptions.Add(testOption);
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();

```
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.QuestionID = new SelectList(db.TestQuestions, "", "", testOption.QuestionID);
        return View(testOption);
    }
```

I desire to display the question just entered by the user in the Create method of the option controller so that the user would enter the options for question.

The program create a dropdownlist of all the questions l've enter before, but I want only the last  question should show in the redirected view.

Comment: thanks this was helpful. basically, since move involved only one field the second answer also handled it well.  thank you